# R-Geocoding => Lots of NA

Tags: r, ggmap, geocode

I am trying to geocode locations, for a CSV file of 200 addresses (address+postal code+city). I am using the geocode function.

I am able to get 60% of results, but many addresses return NA (longitude and latitude).

This is weird, as I am getting some answers when re-running the query for just one address (just to check). It seems the addresses are randomly "recognized".

The code is below.

Thanks for your help !

```
 data <- read.csv2("agencies.csv",header=T,sep=";") #Loading the file
 colnames(data) <- "addresses" #Changing column name
 data$addresses <- paste0(data$addresses, ", France") #Adding country to make address easier to find

 output <- geocode(data$addresses, output = "latlona")
```

Comment: Could you provide some examples in which this happens?

Comment: Can you provide a copy of your csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need more or different information, such as a zip code to go with just city/state:

geocode("West Point, NY")
vs
geocode("West Point, NY 10996")